# fluid simulation baking error

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

What I am trying is following:
I want to "melt" a human body, so that the body turns into water and splashes onto the ground. OR that the human body is melting.
Basically: to turn a more complex form/object into fluid.

The problem I have is the following:
When I bake the body (selected as fluid > fluid) the body turns into a weird shape and splashed onto the floor (fluid > obstacle). But I need the body staying exactly in form and melting down from there.

The first picture is the bodyshape before I bake it and the second one you can see what it turns into when baking it (BEFORE it splashes down to the floor)

something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx5KCEX6SZ0
BUT of course not turn into smoke, but water, splashing onto the floor.

[image: before bake]
[image: after bake]

Comment: I think you might have your images reversed.

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for answearing! What do you mean by that? And where can I hange it? Thanks again!! x M

Comment: when i choose volume initialization: shell, it comes closer to the original form, but even when i put the final domain resolution up to 200 before baking it, it has still way less verticles than the original body

Comment: I was just talking about your 2 images in your question, I think they might be backwards.

Comment: ah yes, that is right, i changed it

Comment: Can you show a blend file?

Comment: It definitely should work if your human mesh is a nice clean non-manifold mesh. Here is a test I did: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ac0nygtnuaie4t/meltHuman.blend?dl=0

Comment: Have you try to recalculate normals? You can also try to apply object transform

Comment: Try making the viscosity of the fluid slightly higher, subdividing the fluid, and using surface smoothing.